# Animated GIF as Background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I am trying to make the background of my app an animated gif. This is my code by i am getting the error 'exc_bad_instruction' for this line: images.append(UIImage(named: imageNames[i])!)

I don't see what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
var imageNames = ["tmp-0.gif", "tmp-1.gif", "tmp-2.gif", "tmp-3.gif", "tmp-4.gif", "tmp-5.gif", "tmp-6.gif", "tmp-7.gif", "tmp-8.gif", "tmp-9.gif", "tmp-10.gif", "tmp11.gif", "tmp-12.gif", "tmp-13.gif", "tmp-14.gif", "tmp-15.gif", "tmp-16.gif", "tmp-17.gif", "tmp-18.gif", "tmp-19.gif"]

    var images = [UIImage]()

    for i in 0..<imageNames.count{
        images.append(UIImage(named: imageNames[i])!)

    }

    theGif.animationImages = images
    theGif.animationDuration = 1.0
    theGif.startAnimating()
```

Comment: What is logged to the console?  Most likely, `UIImage(named:)` returned `nil`.

Comment: Make sure the gifs are all included in the target (the checkboxes should be checked in the right toolpane) and that you've spelled everything right.

Comment: @keithbhunter how do i include the gifs in the target

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering using an animated GIF for the background, instead of trying to decouple all of the frames in the GIF and using the animation capabilities of `UIImageView`, I'd recommend using a proper animated GIF library.

[Flipboard's FLAnimatedImage library](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) is apparently one of the more popular ones (I haven't used it personally, so I can't say for sure). It's Objective-C, but it should interoperate with Swift with no issues.